# How can you bind to the visual contents of a ContentPresenter in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ContentPresenter in a UserControl. The content of the ContentPresenter is a data object, and a datatyped DataTemplate defines the UI for the ContentPresenter (the root of which is another UserControl).

A button in the outer UserControl needs to have its content bound to the value of an attached property defined on the inner UserControl hosted by the ContentPresenter. How do I do this in XAML?

More widely what are good ways for visual objects defined in different namescopes or across a template boundary to interact?

Comment: You shouldn't really be doing that...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In the end I sorted it from code-behind. There are some things that XAML is just not good at.

I needed to bind the Top property of the root UserControl of my DataTemplate to the Canvas.Top attached property of the ContentPresenter that contained it. In my case the ContentPresenter was being generated by an ItemsControl that was applying the DataTemplate to the underlying data object collection. The Content property of the ContentPresenter pointed to the underlying data object rather than the Visual object that I needed to reference. Although this isn't exactly the problem you face, I think the crux of it is the same - trying to find a reference to the Visual content of a ContentPresenter.

In the code behind for the innermost UserControl, I wired up the binding by overriding the EndInit method. I was only ever planning to use the control in one situation so this was acceptable for me, but the code could be moved elsewhere as applicable to your situation.

```
/// <summary>
/// Indicates that the initialization process for the element is complete
/// </summary>
public override void EndInit()
{
    this.BindToParentContentPresenter();
    base.EndInit();
}

/// <summary>
/// Binds the Canvas.Top attached property of the content presenter to the top property of this object
/// </summary>
private void BindToParentContentPresenter()
{
    ContentPresenter cp = this.VisualParent as ContentPresenter;
    if (cp != null)
    {
        Binding b = new Binding();
        b.Source = this;
        b.Path = new PropertyPath(TopProperty);
        cp.SetBinding(SelectableUniformCanvas.TopProperty, b);
    }
}
```